# Remote desktop select which printer from local resource

Tags: remote-desktop, printer

When connecting to Windows XP via Remote Desktop (mstsc), you can select which local resources you want to take with you to the remote desktop (disc drives, clipboard, printers).

Is there a way to select which printer specifically you want to take with you?

Right now, some printers are copied, some are not, but I can't find WHY some are not available, or why others are.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: there is no answer yet on the question if only certain printers can be taken to the remote desktop, but I think it can not be selected in any way.

Answer (score 4):

The reason some printers are available and some are not is that for a a printer to be available, the driver for that printer has to be installed on the server. If  you look in he event log of the server you will likely see Terminal Services errors for the printers that don't show up, because the drivers not there.

The easiest way to get the drivers on there is to add a new printer on a com port (in the printer wizard, not physically), so that it asks you for the driver, specify the driver then hen the install is complete, delete the printer. Next time you login the printer should be available.

Comment: Thanks. The driver indeed needs to be EXACTLY the same (after using the same installation files on both pc's, the printer was taken to the remote desktop)